# Symlink some folders in home directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, permissions, symbolic-link

I recently installed dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 on a new machine. I followed a guide which suggested giving `/home` a 10GB partition and throwing the rest in `/`. I started putting all my documents and media files in `/home` and quickly ran out of space. In hindsight, I would not have given myself so little space on `/home`, but I am unwilling to reformat and start again.

A simple solution is to symlink specific subfolders `/home/username/bigstuff` out to a folder on the big partition, say `/media/extra-space/username/bigstuff`. A detailed way of doing this is outlined by Paul's answer [in this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/465493/how-can-i-symlink-my-home-folder-from-another-drive). This works fine, except the permissions seem to be such that I cannot do anything in `/home/username/bigstuff` without a `sudo`.

I have three questions, with the last one being the most important for me:

1. <strike>Is this solution appropriate, or would it make experienced users weep? Should I be using a different directory, perhaps simply `/extra-space/username/bigstuff` ?</strike>
2. <strike>I am misunderstanding something basic: if `/home` is a subdirectory of `/`, how can it be on a separate partition? (This is what got me in the first place.)</strike> (answered)
3. How can I avoid having to write `sudo` every time I want to execute a command in `/home/username/bigstuff` (which is really on `/media/extra-space/username/bigstuff`)? I've tried changing the permissions on `/media/extra-space/username` but was not successful.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT in response to comments:

The output of `stat --format=%m /media/extra-space/username/bigstuff` is `/`. The output of `stat --file-system --format=%T /media/extra-space/username/bigstuff` is `ext2/ext3`. I'm not sure how to identify the relevant line of output from `mount`. The output of `ls -ld /media/extra/username/bigstuff` is

`drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Feb 13 16:26 /media/extra/username/bigstuff`

If it helps, in System Monitor, I see the following File Systems:

```
Device      Directory  Type 
/dev/sdb7   /          ext4
/dev/sdb1   /boot/efi  vfat
/dev/sdb5   /home      ext4
```

To be clear, I get a permission denied for `mkdir` when in `~/username/bigstuff`, but it does seem correctly symlinked because after doing `sudo mkdir test`, `/media/extra/username/bigstuff/test` appears.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Thanks for the links. The first two links address the first two questions, while the third discusses permissions for mounts rather than symlinks. It seems `mount.ntfs-3g` may still be the utility of choice. Do I understand correctly that I should read carefully read the documentation of this driver and attempt to change permissions on my symlink? Thanks again.

Comment: What is the filesystem that holds `/media/extra-space/username/bigstuff`? How do you mount it? With what options? For a start please post the relevant line from the output of `mount`.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski  I don't want to mount it, `/media` is simply on the same partition as my installation of  Ubuntu is on. `/home/username/bigstuff` is symlinked to `/media/extra-space/username/bigstuff`, but when I try to execute commands such as `mkdir` within `.../bigstuff`, I need to prefix it with `sudo`. I want to avoid that. Using `chown` didn't work. I'm sure there's a simple way of adding permissions, I just don't know how.

Comment: You already have mounted some filesystem(s). What is the output of `stat --format=%m /media/extra-space/username/bigstuff`? What is the output of `stat --file-system --format=%T /media/extra-space/username/bigstuff`? What is the relevant line from the output of `mount`?

Comment: What is the output of `ls -ld /media/extra-space/username/bigstuff`?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I have added the output in the OP.

Comment: `bigstuff` is owned by `root` and the permissions are `rwxr-xr-x`; it's normal a regular user cannot create a new directory in `bigstuff`. **But** you wrote "I cannot do anything" and "avoid having to write `sudo` every time I want to execute a command in `bigstuff`" which I interpret as "any command (e.g. `date` or `sleep 1`) does not work in `bigstuff`" or "no executable like `./foo` can be executed in `bigstuff`". The former would be very weird; the latter could be explained, but not (easily) in your current setup. So please clarify "I cannot do anything".

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I was wrong and should have said I can't create directories but can execute commands (such as `date` or `sleep 1`). I also poked around more and paid attention to permissions/ownership and was able to resolve the issue (see edit). If you want to post a short answer I can accept it so that the question is answered. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I don't want to post an answer. [You can](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer). Please move your solution to an answer, it doesn't belong to the question.

Answer (score 0):

To recap, I:

- Created a directory `extra/username/bigstuff` in `/media`, which is on the device `/dev/sdb7`
- Ran `ln -s /media/extra/username/bigstuff /home/username/bigstuff`
- After Kamil pointed out that `bigstuff` is owned by root, I ran `sudo -R chown username:username bigstuff`. I also ran `sudo chmod +w bigstuff`. Now, `ls -ld /media/extra/username/bigstuff` gives
  `drwxrwxr-x 3 username username 4096 Feb 13 16:19 /media/extra/username/bigstuff`

Then I started poking more and got confused because I could create directories and files in *subdirectories* of `.../bigstuff`, but not in `/bigstuff`. I also saw that the owner name/group of `/media/extra/username` was still `root:root`. I `sudo chown`'ed that and that resolved my issues (can now create directories in `.../bigstuff`).